# How to reduce the quality of streaming on Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, youtube, streaming, data-monitoring

I recently upgraded from Galaxy S1 (Android 2.3.5) to S4 (SGH-I337M with Android 4.4.2)

The thing is before I couldn't have the Chrome browser because was not compatible and my YouTube app played videos just in HQ.

But now my S4 plays streaming in HD (720p). I set the option to see videos in HD (YouTube) only on WI-FI but even though I did this, my data plan is being devoured. 
When I see streaming from pages in Chrome, they are also spending my data plan.

I know this thanks to the data usage application in android (Apps > Settings > Data usage) and match exactly with my internet provider consumption plan.

**How can I do to reduce the streaming quality in general on my S4 in order to reduce the consumption of my data plan.**

I tried to ask the same thing in google but mostly all the pages advice to do the opposite, I mean... how to increase the video quality on android.

It doesn't bother me to see videos in HQ like before.

Thanks.